# How to process streaming FX data and calculate live-stream ATR()?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading

I am trying out algorithmic trading with python, for backtesting.

First I downloaded some tick data, then resampled them as 10 second OHLC-data, and then used ATR-indicator, as a defined function:

```
     df = pd.read_csv( 'gbpusd jan17.csv',
                        names       = ['instrument', 'time', 'bid', 'ask'],
                        index_col   = 1,
                        parse_dates = True,
                        nrows       = 1000
                        )
     df = df['ask'].resample('10s').ohlc()
     n  = list( range( 0, len( df.index ) ) ) # I changed index because my indicator
                                              # doesn't work on datetime index      
     df.index = n

     def ATR(df, n): #________________________# Average True Range  
         i    = 0  
         TR_l = [0]  
         while i < df.index[-1]:
            TR = max( df.get_value( i + 1, 'high' ),
                      df.get_value( i,     'close' )
                      )
               - min( df.get_value( i + 1, 'low' ),
                      df.get_value( i,     'close' )
                      )
            TR_l.append( TR )
            i = i + 1  
         TR_s = pd.Series( TR_l )  
         ATR  = pd.Series( TR_s.rolling( window      = 12,
                                         min_periods = 12,
                                         center      = False
                                         ).mean(),
                           name = 'ATR_' + str(n)
                           )
         df  = df.join( ATR )
         return df

   Outputs: head()
                                 instrument      bid      ask
      time                                                
      2017-01-02 00:00:01.105    GBP/USD         1.23399  1.23551
      2017-01-02 00:00:01.561    GBP/USD         1.23399  1.23551
      2017-01-02 00:00:05.122    GBP/USD         1.23399  1.23551
      2017-01-02 00:00:05.525    GBP/USD         1.23365  1.23577
      2017-01-02 00:00:06.139    GBP/USD         1.23365  1.23577 

      open     high     low      close    ATR_8
    \
      1.23562  1.23562  1.23562  1.23562  0.000120   0.596718     
      1.23562  1.23575  1.23548  1.23548  0.000121   0.619445     
      1.23548  1.23548  1.23541  1.23541  0.000122   0.645532    
      1.23541  1.23541  1.23541  1.23541  0.000117   0.674178   
      1.23541  1.23548  1.23541  1.23548  0.000123   0.687229
```

But, the problem starts when I connect to Oanda API to get streaming rates, the while loop for ATR calculation doesn't seem to work, firstly I thought, it's not working because of, not enough rows of data at the begining, so I made ATR calculation start after certain ticks, still not working.

Can any one help with the **`while`** loop, how should I change for the streaming data?